# Calculating the polar of a given pole relative to a conic (with NO Calculus)

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, analytic-geometry, projective-geometry, computer-vision

Let $M$ be the matrix of the conic 
$$Ax^{2}+Bxy+Cy^{2}+Dx+Ey+F=0$$
so we have:
$$M=\left[\begin{array}{ccc} A&\displaystyle{\frac{B}{2}}&\displaystyle{\frac{D}{2}}\\ \displaystyle{\frac{B}{2}}&C&\displaystyle{\frac{E}{2}}\\ \displaystyle{\frac{D}{2}}&\displaystyle{\frac{E}{2}}&F\end{array}\right]$$
What is the simplest way **with no Differential Calculus** to show that:

> The coefficients $P_1,Q_1,R_1$ equation of the **[Polar Line](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polar.html)** $P_1x+Q_1y+R_1=0$ that passes by an exterior point **(a pole**) $(x_0,y_0)$ is given by the matrix product of $M$ and the column ${\mathbf{x}}=(x_0,y_0,1)^{t}$, that is:
>   $$
> M\left[
> \begin{array}{c} 
> x_0\\ 
> y_0\\
> 1 
> \end{array}
> \right]=\left[
> \begin{array}{c} 
> P_1\\ 
> Q_1\\
> R_1 
> \end{array}
> \right]$$
>
> I tried considering a line that passes through $(x_0,y_0)$:
>   $$P_1(x-x_0)+Q_1(y-y_0)=0$$
>   and considering two separated cases: $P_1\neq 0$ and $Q_1\neq 0$ to replace $x$ or $y$ in the conic equation and saying that the discriminant of the resulting 2nd degree equation is zero to get conditions on $P_1$, $Q_1$ and $R_1$ to show the assertion but I got stuck.

[image]

this image came from http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polar.html

Comment: This doesn't make sense: the point $(x_0, y_0)$ doesn't appear anywhere in the final expression. Is the line defined by this expression supposed to pass through ALL points of the plane?

Comment: You right exactly :)

Comment: I correct the assertion. Thank you very much

Comment: Do you have some other definition of the polar line to which you’re trying to show equivalence? Otherwise, there’s nothing to prove here. Also, I don’t really understand why you’re looking at a parallel line through $(x_0,y_0)$. A point only lies on its polar line if the point is on the conic, in which case the polar is the tangent at that point.

Comment: Yes, see here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polar.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the map $\pi$ from the set of points to the set of lines given by matrix product with $M$. You want to check that $\pi(P)=AB$.

Step 1. Check the following proposition: if $\pi(X)$ passes through $Y$, then $\pi(Y)$ passes through $X$. Use that $M$ is symmetric. Note: a line $Px+Qy+R=0$ passes through a point $(x_0,y_0)$ if and only if for $p=(P,Q,R),x=(x_0,y_0,1)$ we have $x\cdot p^t=0$ (here $t$ denotes the transpose of a matrix).

Step 2. Show that it is enough to check that $\pi(A)$ is the tangent $AP$ (similarly, $\pi(B)=BP$).

Step 3. Check that $\pi(A)$ passes through $A$ and it is the only point of intersection of $\pi(A)$ and the conic. Use that a line $XY$ has parametric equation $tX+(1-t)Y$.

Comment: Excellent answer