# Transforming Euclidean figures

Tags: geometry

By their nature, Euclidean theorems do not specify lengths. Where a line has zero length a consistent interpretation is (almost?) always possible and is frequently instructive. Is there a theorem which enshrines (or constrains) this principle?

Comment: See Klein's [Erlangen program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlangen_program) and [Affine geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_geometry). In Euclid's *Elements* there is no [metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space)

Comment: That's right: I need to move up a level in generality.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you, when you use the verb "enshrines", you are thinking more to axioms than theorems, isn't it ?

I don't think that any valuable axiom/result can be edicted regarding a zero distance **between points**: saying that $A$ is at distance 0 from $B$ means plainly that $A$ and $B$ are two namings for the same point.

But it can become interesting in the context of the distance **from a point to a straight line**. Let us consider in particular the context of [pole-polar line duality](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2609629). There is a result saying the fact that a pole is at distance zero from its polar line with respect to a conic curve $C$ iff the pole is on $C$ and its polar line is the tangent line at this point to $C$.

I see another direction of thought: as you entitle your question "transforming figures", have you considered infinitesimal transformations ?

Comment: What I had in mind were cases like Brahmagupta's formula for the area of a cyclic quadrilateral which becomes Heron's formula for the area of a triangle when one side shrinks to zero. But I guess you're right: I'm looking for an axiom rather than a theorem to justify the use of such special cases.

Comment: I see. There is a cousin result about the [Cayley-Menger determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Menger_determinant) which "shrinks" to $0$ if, in 3D, 4 points $A,B,C,D$ are coplanar for the reason that it is proportional to the (square of) the volume of tetrahedron $ABCD$.